# How to format array list to json

Tags: javascript, json

**I am trying to get the json object from array list**

```
arrayList [
0: {name: "01", value: "3424234234"} 
1: {name: "17", value: "26021734"}
2: {name: "10", value: "435345"} 
3: {name: "21", value: "3453"}]
```

I have converted above array to json like below

```
var getCode={};
getCode = Object.assign({}, arrayList );
```

I am getting the result as below

```
getCode 
{
0: {name: "01", value: "3424234234"} 
1: {name: "17", value: "26021734"} 
2: {name: "10", value: "435345"} 
3: {name: "21", value: "3453"} 
}
```

**But I need the result as follows**

```
aiCode: 
{
01: "3424234234", 
17: "26021734", 
10: "435345", 
21: "3453"
}
```

How can I get the JSON stringified as above

Comment: For the record, you are turning an Array into an Object. Using the word JSON, which is a text format, in this context is confusing.

Comment: Please use the correct tags so users that can answer your question can find it. The tags you *had* selected were not relevant to angular or angularjs. This question was about javascript and json, nothing more was needed.

Comment: This question seemingly has nothing to do with JSON

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method.

```
var res = arrayList
  // iterate over the array
  .reduce((obj, o) => {
    // define property 
    obj[o.name] = o.value;
    // return the object
    return obj;
    // set initial value as an empty object
  }, {})
```

```js
var arrayList = [{
    name: "01",
    value: "3424234234"
  },
  {
    name: "17",
    value: "26021734"
  },
  {
    name: "10",
    value: "435345"
  },
  {
    name: "21",
    value: "3453"
  }
];

var res = arrayList.reduce((obj, o) => {
  obj[o.name] = o.value;
  return obj;
}, {})

console.log(res)
```

---

Same with [ES6 object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

```
var res = arrayList.reduce((obj, { name, value }) => {
  obj[name] = value;
  return obj;
}, {})
```

```js
var arrayList = [{
    name: "01",
    value: "3424234234"
  },
  {
    name: "17",
    value: "26021734"
  },
  {
    name: "10",
    value: "435345"
  },
  {
    name: "21",
    value: "3453"
  }
];

    

console.log(res)
```

One-liner solution with [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) :

```
var res = arrayList.reduce((obj, { name, value }) => ({ [name] : value, ...obj }), {})
```

Or

```
var res = arrayList.reduce((obj, { name, value }) => (obj[name] = value, obj ), {})
```

Comment: Thanks. works perfectly