# Change array in javascript into simpler object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a simple JSON with an array that contains further objects, etc. like this:

```
languagePack:
[
  {
    'key': 'Username',
    'value': 'Benutzername',
    'group': 'default'
  },
  {
    'key': 'Password',
    'value': 'Passwort',
    'group': 'default'
  }
]
```

But what I really want is an object like this:

```
languagePack: 
{
    'Username': 'Benutzername',
    'Password': 'Passwort'
}
```

So, I want to reduce the array to simple key-value-pairs that are inside an array or even an object (keys are unique). Does anyone have an idea how to reduce this with some of these cool array functions? I only came up with something like an for each and building the object "by hand" property for property, but  I remember there were some cool things for array like 'reduce', the spread operator (...), map, every, some, etc.

I tried it with something like:

```
var temp = this.languagePack.map(([key, value]) => ({key,value}))
console.log(temp)
```

But that only got me an error message `TypeError: Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance`

Edit: All three answers are working perfectly fine. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format array list to json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55184187)

Comment: The `group` shall be ignored?

Comment: Yes, the group can be ignored, it was only an idea of my coworker to use the same key in different screens with different translations, but I cannot find any real use for it. But that is another question for much later :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Basically you need to use `forEach` instead of `map` function and then you can build that object to whatever key, value pair you want to keep.

**Try this, it will solve your problem.**

```
var temp = {};

this.languagePack.forEach(({key,value}) => {
    temp[key] = value
})

console.log(temp)
```

**Note:** Here we are not using `map` because we want to return object not an array, so, we can use `reduce` function here to do so, but I thought this would be simple and easy to understand what we want and what are we doing here.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the javascript `reduce` function to create an empty object and put each key and value in it.

```js
const data = [
  {
    'key': 'Username',
    'value': 'Benutzername',
    'group': 'default'
  },
  {
    'key': 'Password',
    'value': 'Passwort',
    'group': 'default'
  }
];

const newData = data.reduce((acc, row) => {
  acc[row.key] = row.value;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(newData);
```

Edit : Nice suggest of **Donny Verduijn**.
You can use es6 destructuring to write the function shorter.

```
const newData = data.reduce((acc, { key, value }) => ({ ...acc, [key]: value }), {});
```

Comment: If you like to use ES6 syntax you can also implement the reduce function this way `(acc, { key, value }) => ({ ...acc, [key]: value })`

Comment: Also, you can use the comma operator to avoid the return:
`const newData = data.reduce((acc, row) => (acc[row.key] = row.value, acc), {});`

Comment: Just as a curiosity. Some time ago I was testing the performance of the spread operator to destructuring objects, and even if it is true that sometimes it improves the readability of the code, it has a high cost: https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/6194/5/compare-spread-operator-and-concat-in-arrays

Comment: @ElChiniNet The test case you linked is about array spread, not object spread. (But yes, repeatedly spreading into a new object is far slower than mutating a single object)

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use reduce here since the accumulator is the same object throughout the process.

Comment: @Bergi, here you have a comparison of this specific code: https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/6318/0/compare-spread-operator-in-objects-vs-set-the-propertie

Comment: @Nikolai, maybe I didn't get the point of your comment, but could you elaborate on why do you think that it doesn't make sense to use `reduce` here?

Comment: @ElChiniNet `reduce` is used to update the accumulator value between iterations. Here the value stays the same, you just add properties to it. It would be clearer to use `forEach` as the accepted answer suggests.

Comment: @Nikolai, I think that in this case that is your particular opinion, [even in the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) one can find examples using as an accumulator an array or an object. There are multiple answers here, each one can be clearer or preferred for different people, IMO this is something good from SO.

Answer (score 6):

use with `Array#map` its create the key and value as object and `Object.assign` covert array value to object

```js
const languagePack = [ { 'key': 'Username', 'value': 'Benutzername', 'group': 'default' }, { 'key': 'Password', 'value': 'Passwort', 'group': 'default' } ];

var res = Object.assign({},...languagePack.map(({key,value}) => ({[key]:value})))

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use ES6 `Map` for that use `Object.fromEntries` to convert `map` back to `Object`.

For more information about [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

```js
let languagePack=
[{
  'key': 'Username',
  'value': 'Benutzername',
  'group': 'default'
},
{
  'key': 'Password',
  'value': 'Passwort',
  'group': 'default'
}];

let map = new Map();

languagePack.forEach((val)=>{
  map.set(val.key, val.value);
})
languagePack = Object.fromEntries(map);
console.log(languagePack);
```